# Get font name of .ttf file

Tags: c#, .net, fonts

Lets say there is a .ttf (True Type Font) file. You can install it on windows with a click. The real name of the font is not the text that is before the .tff (lets say SuperFont.ttf => so the name is not "SuperFont" - it could be, but mostly not). I would like to read the .tff (somehow?) and get the name (without installing the font) of the font. Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll need to add the font to a private collection (`PrivateFontCollection`), then request the `FontFamily` instance and get its `Name` property.

Like this:

```
PrivateFontCollection fontCol = new PrivateFontCollection();
fontCol.AddFontFile(@"PATH TO FONT");
Console.WriteLine(fontCol.Families[0].Name);
```

You'll need the namespaces:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
```

MSDN: [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx), [FontFamily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontfamily.aspx)

Comment: _(without installing the font)_

Comment: This doesn't install the font. Although MSDN uses the term "install" they're using it lightly. "`This is a temporary font install that does not affect the system-installed collection.`" Install here basically means "loaded".

Comment: This gets the font family name (e.g. "Open Sans"), but not the full name with the style.  For example, every .ttf file for open sans will have the name "Open Sans", not "Open Sans Italic" or "Open Sans Bold".

Answer (score 3):

Here is the another code to extract fontname without using System.Drawing dll

```
foreach (FontFamily fontFamily in Fonts.GetFontFamilies("file:///D:/MyFonts/"))
{
    string name = fontFamily .ToString().Split('#')[fontFamily .ToString().Split('#').Count() - 1];
}
```