# How to get the font name from a ttf file in .Net Core

Tags: c#, fonts, .net-core

I am trying to migrate my MVC 6 project to .NET Core 2.0 and we all know that lots of things are missing or is still in the development phase.

I have a **fonts**  folder containaing a number of **.ttf** files. My objective here is to retrieve all the **Font Family Names** from those **ttf** files.

Previously, I was using the **PrivateFontCollection** under the **System.Drawing.Text namespace**. The code was something like the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885259/get-font-name-of-ttf-file).

But it is not working in .NET Core.

Am I missing a dll reference or is there another way to do it in .NET Core.

Here is a sample of what i really want :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great!!! It seems someone provided a mono implementation of System.Drawing. 
[CoreCompat.System.Drawing](https://github.com/CoreCompat/System.Drawing)

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core >= 2.1 now supports [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/). This is a Microsoft supported library which includes PrivateFontCollection.